# password confirmation not allow 3 digit password

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a simple password confirmation, that will auto check password if matched without clicking the submit button.

If not matched the button is disabled and if password matches, the button is enabled.

Now, is there a way that the code will check if the
password has at least 5 digits in it. 
If not, it should show a message that he/she must enter at least 5 digits for password.

This is my current script for checking password:

```
   <script>
     $('#password, #password1').on('keyup', function () {
      if (!$('#password').val()) {
        $('#message').html('');
      } else {
          if ($('#password').val() == $('#password1').val()) {
            $('#message').html('Password Match').css('color', 'green');
             $('#submit').prop('disabled', false);
          } else {
            $('#message').html('Password not Match').css('color', 'red');
             $('#submit').prop('disabled', true);
        }
      }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You mean you want to see if the password contains at least 5 digits or it at least more than 5 characters?

Comment: yes, or it will check if the is atleast 5 digits on it

Comment: The reason I ask is because digits are numbers meaning you require a minimum of 5 numbers in the password.I wanted to clear up any confusion but since the answer below has been accepted I can only assume you mean a minimum password length of 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following validation to your code

```
 if ($('#password').val().length < 5) {
                $('#message').html('Password must be at least 5 digits').css('color', 'red');
                $('#submit').prop('disabled', true);
              }
```

Comment: i tried puting the code on top of if but for some reason its not working, im sorry im a beginner at javascript and jquery.

Comment: If you want to make the validation on the keyup function you got there, try adding it in before this line `if ($('#password').val() == $('#password1').val()) {`